# ASP.NET MVC: deployment issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, medium-trust

I created an ASP.NET MVC 1.0 application that works fine on my machine (running in vs 2008 web server). However, when I deploy it to my webhost (running in medium trust), I get the following exception on the first hit: could not find file or dependency System, Version 1.0.9.0. Looking at the stack trace, I saw target invocation exception, method not allowed exception (sorry I did not keep the original exception details). My webhost switched my trust level to full trust and it started working.

I thought ASP.Net MVC 1.0 was supposed to work in medium trust?

Comment: Can you elaborate? What does the application do? write to files, just display data from a database? Do some logging, and what kind of logging?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net MVC should indeed run in medium trust, it has been dscussed before on SO - e.g. [What application trust level is need for ASP.NET MVC framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791488/what-application-trust-level-is-need-for-asp-net-mvc-framework)

Clearly your app is doing something which isn't happy in medium trust, can you reproduce and provide more details of the exception?

Comment: I tried to upload the default template mvc web project (which runs fine on my laptop even when I add <trust level="Medium" /> in the web.config) and I had the same error on my host. My project is also working on my laptop with <trust level="Medium" /> in the web.config. I will try to reproduce the exception to add the details to this post. Thank you.